# Duvida sistemas de perguntas e resposta com método $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

Tenho um sistema que mostra uma pergunta e a pessoa responde,só que estou com uma falha,seguinte:
 Quando a pessoal responde passo uso o método $_GET para pegar a resposta dele e inserir as informações no banco,mais a falha e que se a pessoa atualizar a pagina ou coisa assim a informação é inserida 2x no banco,como poderia fazer para fazer somente uma inclusão no banco ?

Formulário:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="comportamento.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Pergunta <?php echo"$ordem";?> de <?php echo"$totalpergunta";?></b></legend>
    <?php
     $timestamp            = @mktime(date("H")-4, date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"),0);
     $data_cad              = gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='loja'         id='loja'         value='$loja'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='id_usuario'   id='id_usuario'   value='$id_usuario'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='questionario' id='questionario' value='$questionario'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='area'         id='area'         value='$area'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='nro_pergunta' id='nro_pergunta' value='$nro_pergunta'>";     
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='data_cad'     id='data_cad'     value='$data_cad'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='pergunta'     id='pergunta'     value='$idpergunta'>";
    ?>
       <?php
        $sql_button = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM respostas WHERE 
           resp_loja='$loja'
       AND resp_usuario='$id_usuario'
       AND resp_area ='$area'
       AND resp_pergunta_id ='$idpergunta'
       AND resp_subgrupo='100'
       AND resp_questionario='$questionario'");

     if(mysql_num_rows ($sql_button) == 0 )
      {
     echo"<div class='form-group'>";
      echo"<center><h4><label> $descpergunta</label></h4></center>";
      echo"<div class='col-lg-10'>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios1' value='5'>OTIMO        </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios2' value='3'>BOM      </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios3' value='2'>REGULAR         </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios3' value='1'>RUIM         </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios4' value='0'>NAO APLICADO </label></div>";
        echo"</div>";
      echo"</div>";
     echo"<div class='form-group'>";
      echo"<div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2'>";
                echo"<button id='button' type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Responder</button><br />";

       echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
    } else  {
    echo"<div class='form-group'>";
      echo"<div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2'>";
            echo"<button id='button' type='next' name='next' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right'></span> Próxima</button><br />";
            echo"<br>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'>";
            echo"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button>";
            echo"<strong>ATENÇÃO! </strong>Você já respondeu essa pergunta.";
            echo"</div>";  
       echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
    }
   ?> 


  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Insert:

```
<?php
 include("conexao.php");
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_usuario   = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["data_cad"]; 

  $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
  (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
  VALUES 
  ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','100','$idpergunta','$resp','$datacad','1')") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao); } 

if(isset($_GET['proxima'])){
$pergunta = (int)$_GET['proxima'];
header('location: comportamento.php?nro_pergunta='.$pergunta);  
}
```

OBS: Postei somente a parte do código referente a pergunta,mais se precisarem de mais alguma informação por favor retornar.

E para concluir,não sei se pode colocar 2 perguntas juntas,mais se puderem responder,é o seguinte:
Na inclusão do banco esta inserindo somente a data,e não data hora como é no campo,seria a forma de inclusão que esta errada?

No mais um forte abraço e até mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo bem simples de resolver esse problema é fazer a mesma verificação que você fez no formulário dentro do insert.

```
   <?php
    include("conexao.php");
                $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
                $id_usuario   = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
                $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
                $area         = $_GET ["area"];
                $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
                $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
                $datacad      = $_GET ["data_cad"]; 

    $sql_button = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM respostas WHERE 
       resp_loja='$loja'
   AND resp_usuario='$id_usuario'
   AND resp_area ='$area'
   AND resp_pergunta_id ='$idpergunta'
   AND resp_subgrupo='100'
   AND resp_questionario='$questionario'");

 if(mysql_num_rows ($sql_button) == 0 )

   {


            if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

              $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
              (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
              VALUES 
              ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','100','$idpergunta','$resp','$datacad','1')") or die (mysql_error());
                mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao); } 

            if(isset($_GET['proxima'])){
            $pergunta = (int)$_GET['proxima'];
            header('location: comportamento.php?nro_pergunta='.$pergunta);  
            }

 } else {

     header("Location: vaParaAlgumLugar.php");

 }

?>
```

Mas, sinceramente, essa não é a melhor forma e nem a mais segura para fazer inserção em DB. Para isso existe o `method="post"`. Pois com ele você sabe realmente se o usuário clicou no `<input type="submit">`. Além disso abre uma porta imensa para hacker 'ligeirão' usar esse método para manipular sua query.
Sem contar que você pode resgatar alguns parâmetros via `$_GET` mesmo usando o metodo `$_POST` no formulário.

Formulários com metodo `$_GET` são bons para fazer uma busca no DB por exemplo. E mesmo assim, você tem que criar classes ou funções de segurança.

Uma dica: procure não usar mais `mysql_*`, mude para `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`, pois o `mysql_*` já está defasado.

Espero que eu tenha te ajudado.

Abraço!

Comment: Tinha postado que o erro continuava,mais na verdade estava passando o parâmetro da query errada,já acertei e deu certo,exatamente da forma que você me passou,Obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo @otacio! Boa sorte!